# Palindromic numbers in C, string error

Tags: c

New to C. Trying to write program that prints out palindromic numbers < 1 million.
Prints out jibberish. Have I made an error with strings?

```
int decimal_pali(int x)
{
   int digits=0;
   int num=x;
   char D[7];
   while(num>0)
   {
       D[digits]=num%10;
       digits+=1;
       num/=10;
   }

   D[digits]='\0';
   num=atoi(D);

   if(num == x)
   {
      return 1;
   }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `D[digits]=num%10;` --> `D[digits]='0' + num%10;`

Comment: Re "new to C", just a suggestion: after you fix it as already pointed out, change it to **any_base_pali(int x, int base)** And now, find out which, if any, numbers are "palindromic" in more than one base.

Comment: `while(num>0)    { ...    }` fails when `num == 0`, Use `do  {  ...  } while (num > 0);` to insure at least 1 digit in `D[]`

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake lies here:

```
D[digits]=num%10;
```

It should be

```
D[digits] = num%10 + '0';
```

`num % 10` will result in a number between 0 and 9 inclusive but since you are working with characters, you need to get the ASCII value of the digit. If you have a look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif), you'll find that in order to achieve what you want, you need to add the ASCII value of `'0'` (48) to the value to get the correct character.

Answer (score 0):

Curiosity wouldn't let me resist the "more than one base" thing, though I doubt the result has any (non-trivial) number-theoretic significance. Anyway, here's the code, and a sample run below that...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  int n1 = ( argc>1? atoi(argv[1]) : 1 ),
      n2 = ( argc>2? atoi(argv[2]) : 999 ),
      b1 = ( argc>3? atoi(argv[3]) : 10 ),
      b2 = ( argc>4? atoi(argv[4]) : 10 );
  int n=n1, b=b1, ispal();
  char *itoa();
  for ( n=n1; n<=n2; n++ ) {
    for ( b=b1; b<=b2; b++ ) if ( !ispal(n,b) ) goto next_n;
    printf("%10d(base10)",n);
    for ( b=b1; b<=b2; b++ ) printf(" = %s(%d)", itoa(n,b),b);
    printf("\n");
    next_n: ; }
  } /* --- end-of-function main() --- */
int  ispal ( int i, int base ) {
  char *itoa(), *a=itoa(i,base);
  int answer=0, k=0,n=strlen(a);
  if ( n > 1 ) {
    for ( k=0; k<n/2; k++ )
      if ( a[k] != a[n-k-1] ) goto end_of_job;
    answer = 1; }
  end_of_job: return ( answer );
  } /* --- end-of-function ispal() --- */
char *itoa ( int i, int base ) {
  static char a[99], digits[99] = /* up to base 65 */
      "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#$*";
  int n = 0;
  while ( 1 ) {
    a[n++] = digits[i%base];
    if ( (i/=base) < 1 ) break; }
  a[n] = '\000';
  return ( a );
  } /* --- end-of-function itoa() --- */
```

I called it palinum.c, and a typical run gives...

```
bash-4.3$ ./palinum 1 9999999 3 4
        10(base10) = 101(3) = 22(4)
       130(base10) = 11211(3) = 2002(4)
     11950(base10) = 121101121(3) = 2322232(4)
    175850(base10) = 22221012222(3) = 222323222(4)
    749470(base10) = 1102002002011(3) = 2312332132(4)
   1181729(base10) = 2020001000202(3) = 10200200201(4)
```

showing just a few numbers between 1 and 10million that are "palindromic" in both base 3 and base 4. The few other tests I did showed nothing simultaneously palindromic in three consecutive bases. But the program's easily changed to permit any set of (non-consecutive) bases. (For a less trivial programming challenge, try multiple threads for several n's at a time.)